# Unable to write value to firebase Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have enabled email (custom) authentication in Firebase , I have set following rules

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth == null", //even non-authorised users CAN read
  ".write": "auth == null" //even non-authorised users CAN write
  }
}
```

Trying to test Firebase using following code

```
    let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let playlists = rootRef.child("playlists")
    playlists.setValue("test")
```

Not sure whats wrong but it gives setValue and RemoveValue Permission denied error.

Unable to understand whats wrong , I am new to Firebase

Comment: try auth === null instead of auth == null. Note that if you do it this way authorised users can't read or write. Is that what you want? Perhaps you meant to just do ".read": "true"?

Comment: @Robert yes you are right its ".read":"true" thanks , add that as answer I will mark it thanks.

Comment: @Robert: `===` and `==` function exactly the same in Firebase security rules, so that won't make a difference. But indeed setting `".read": true` (preferably without quotes around `true` - the result is the same, but the proper boolean is more idiomatic) is the way to accomplish this, as per the ["public" rules in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "true" and true are having same effect .

Comment: That's what I said. But one of them is a proper boolean and the other is a string that just happens to have the same effect. When two approaches have the same effect, pick the one that is designed for that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

These rules allow *everyone* to read and write to your entire Firebase node. Ok for testing but please don't leave it like that as it's totally insecure.

Also note that your code will erase the playlists node each time and overwrite it with

```
your_firebase_ref
   playlists: "test"
```

Just to get you going in the right direction, here's updated code that will create a new node each time it's run.

```
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let playlists = rootRef.child("playlists")
let aNewPlayList = playLists.childByAutoId()
aNewPlayList.setValue("test")
```

which will result in

```
your_firebase_ref
   playlists
      -Yius889jsijs: "test"  //first time it's run
      -YUOmsooaosd9: "test"  //second time it's run
```

the -Y.... key is created by childByAutoId and is generally the way to create children keys within a node.